# Mongodb/Mongoose bulkwrite(upsert) performance issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, mongoose, nosql

I am using mongoDB with mongoose for our Nodejs api where we need to do sort of seed for collections where data-source is a JSON, i am using `Model.bulkwrite` which internally uses mongodb's Bulkwrite(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations).
Code below,

```
await Model.bulkWrite(docs.map(doc => ({
    updateOne: {  ..... } // update document
    insertOne: { ....... } // insert document
    updateOne: {  ..... } // update document
    insertOne: { ....... } // insert document
    .
    .
    .n
})))
```

This works fine for our current use-case with just few hundred documents,
But we are worried about how will it scale,its performance when the number of documents will increase a lot, Like will there be any issues when number of document will be in 10 thousands.
Just want to confirm that are we on the right path or is there any room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Bulkwrite in Mongodb is currently having maximum limit of 100,000 write operations in a single batch. From the docs

> The number of operations in each group cannot exceed the value of the maxWriteBatchSize of the database. As of MongoDB 3.6, this value is 100,000. This value is shown in the isMaster.maxWriteBatchSize field.
>
> This limit prevents issues with oversized error messages. If a group
> exceeds this limit, the client driver divides the group into smaller
> groups with counts less than or equal to the value of the limit. For
> example, with the maxWriteBatchSize value of 100,000, if the queue
> consists of 200,000 operations, the driver creates 2 groups, each with
> 100,000 operations.

So, you won't face any performance issues until you exceed this limit.

For your reference:

- [Mongodb Bulkwrite: db.collection.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)
- [Write Command Batch Limit Size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

Comment: First of all, Thanks a lot, Yes i am aware of these limits and i have been through the docs but there is one more part of the mongoDB doc about bulk operations (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#ordered-operations) which says the limit for operations is 1000 and i have read somewhere that people have faced few issues due to this check this video about the same kind of issue (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mX_BJ8d2ntM), Now i have tried to test my solution on our envs for almost 2k documents and it worked fine(it took 20-30 Seconds) and didn't faced any issues.

Comment: Yes, Mongodb `bulk` is having lesser limit. In the question there was `bulkwrite` that was being used, so I answered it for bulkwrite only.