# MongoDB bulkwrite with upsert option is taking more than a minute for 100k+ records. Is it possible to improve?

Tags: mongodb

I have read the following two questions but did not see a satisfactory solution or suggestion:

- [Performance degrade with Mongo when using bulkwrite with upsert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047632/performance-degrade-with-mongo-when-using-bulkwrite-with-upsert)
- [Mongodb/Mongoose bulkwrite(upsert) performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045490/mongodb-mongoose-bulkwriteupsert-performance-issues)

I have an API that will be receiving ~80k objects every 5 - 6 seconds.

These objects will need to be inserted if they do not exist and updated if they do exist.

The collection has a unique index (of type asc 1), which I use in the filter expression below.

Upserting 100k documents using the code below takes more than a minute, which is too long for my requirement (instantiating the objects takes less than a second).

```
MongoClient _mongoClient = new MongoClient("connection string");

IMongoDatabase _hotsauceOdds = _mongoClient.GetDatabase("DatabaseName");

var collection = _hotsauceOdds.GetCollection<Person>("TestMongo");

List<Person> peeps = new List<Person>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    peeps.Add(new Person { Age = i, Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
}

var models = peeps.Select(item => new ReplaceOneModel<Person>(new ExpressionFilterDefinition<Person>(doc => doc.Name == item.Name), item) { IsUpsert = true });

await collection.BulkWriteAsync(models);
```

I am testing this on the free tier of mongo atlas.

Is it possible to make this operation run more quickly, or is this as good as it gets for mongodb?